# Custom Action Install runs on Windows 7 but not on XP when update setup project to VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-xp, windows-installer

I had a msi installer which has custom action install and uninstall runs perfectly on windows xp and 7. That project was on vs 2005. Then I update that to vs 2010. Now it works fine in windows 7
but when I try to install it on windows xp sp3, it is not working. 
I'm getting "`There is a problem with this windows installer package...`" error. It seems my custom action install don't get start from the msi.
what could have gone wrong?

Comment: You can check the Windows event log and it would give you some more specific information regarding the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was I'm missing mfc100.dll in Win XP. When I installed  Visual C++ redistributable package 2010 for Windows form it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely a dependency problem.  It's hard to say without knowing what language your CA is written in (C++?)  but check that you have the right dependencies either linked to your CA or installed on the target machine.  [Depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is your friend.